# ubuntu crontab celery beat

Tags: linux, cron, celery

I have several celery tasks that execute via beat. In development, I used a single command to set this up, like:

```
celery worker -A my_tasks -n XXXXX@%h -Q for_mytasks -c 1 -E -l INFO -B -s ./config/celerybeat-schedule --pidfile ./config/celerybeat.pid
```

On moving to production, I inserted this into a script that activated my venv, set the PYTHONPATH, removed old beat files, cd to correct directory and then run celery. This works absolutely fine. However, in production I want to separate the worker from the beat scheduler, like:

```
celery worker -A my_tasks -n XXXXX@%h -Q for_mytasks -c 1 -E -l INFO -f ./logs/celeryworker.log
celery beat -A my_tasks -s ./config/celerybeat-schedule --pidfile ./config/celerybeat.pid -l INFO -f ./logs/celerybeat.log
```

Now this all works fine when put into the relevant bash scripts. However, I need these to be run on server start-up. I encountered several problems:

1) in crontab -e `@reboot my_script` will not work. I have to insert a delay to allow rabbitmq to fully start, i.e. `@reboot sleep 60 && my_script`. Now this seems a little 'messy' to me but I can live with it.

2) `celery worker` takes several seconds to finish before `celery beat` can be run properly. I tried all manner of cron directives to accomplish beat being run after worker has executed successfully but couldn't get the beat to run. My current solution in crontab is something like this:

```
@reboot sleep 60 && my_script_worker
@reboot sleep 120 && my_script_beat
```

So basically, ubuntu boots, waits 60 seconds and runs celery worker then waits another 60 seconds before running celery beat. This works fine but it seems even more 'messy' to me. In an ideal world I would like to flag when rabbitmq is ready to run worker, then flag when worker has executed successfully so that I can run beat.

My question is : has anybody encountered this problem and if so do they have a more elegant way of kicking off celery worker & beat on server reboot?

EDIT: 24/09/2019
Thanks to DejanLekic & Greenev

I have spent some hours converting from cron to systemd. Yes, I agree totally that this is a far more robust solution. My celery worker & beat are now started as services by systemd on reboot.

There is one tip I have for people trying this that is not mentioned in the celery documentation. The template beat command will create a 'celery beat database' file called `celerybeat-schedule` in your working directory. If you restart your beat service, this file will cause spurious celery tasks to be spawned that don't seem to fit with your actual celery schedule. The solution is to delete this file each time the beat service starts. I also delete the pid file, if it's there. I did this by adding 2 ExecStartPre and a -s option to the beat service :

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c 'rm -f ${CELERYBEAT_DB_FILE}'
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c 'rm -f ${CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE}'
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} beat  \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE} \
  -s ${CELERYBEAT_DB_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL}'
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is to run Celery beat process as a systemd or SysV service. It is described in depth in the [Daemonization](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html) section of the Celery documentation. In fact, same goes for the worker process too.

Why? - Unlike your solution, which involves crontab with @reboot line, systemd for an example can check the health of the service and restart it if needed. All Linux services on your Linux boxes are started this way because it has been made for this particular purpose.

Answer (score 1):

To daemonize celery worker we are using `systemd`, so the worker and the beat could be getting to run as separate services and configured to start on the server reboot via just making these services `enabled`